# Building a <select> form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ok so I want a drop down select form that when selected on a certain state the user will be redirected to that state's page that I have on my website (www.mysite.com/california)

```
 <div id="DropDown">
 <h3 class="Header">Pick Your State</h3>

 <select id="state">
     <option value="www.mysite.com/california">California</option>
     <option value="www.mysite.com/utah">Utah</option>
 </select>

 </div>
```

What do I need to do so it executes the option values and redirects the user to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need js/jquery for this. Wordpress has jQuery so something like this would suffice:

```
$('select#state').on('change', function() {
    window.location.replace($(this).children('option:selected').val());
});
```

Comment: actually it is on a per theme basis.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a redirect in javascript or jquery.

Something like what is suggested on the following page:

[How do I create a drop-down menu that redirects to a new page when selected?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/f/blfaqddredirect.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider doing a `<select>` with a button versus this. This behavior is really annoying for people who use the keyboard or assistive technologies such as a screen reader.

Comment: Would you happen to have some code to direct me with that so that when the user presses the button they will be redirected.

Comment: That is form basics, to be honest, but look at: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php. How are you building the form?